# Mask the last 4 digit in an account number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to do an Select on a table that has many records to mask the Account Number.

Example AccNumber : 123400012341234

Output result should look like 12340001234XXXX

the last 4 digits should become X's.

I come up with this so far

```
select SUBSTRING('XXXX', 0, 4 - len(RIGHT(AccNumber, 4))) + RIGHT(AccNumber, 4) from table
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Did you try your code?

Comment: Yes blorgbeard I am just getting 1234 as result

Comment: Did you look up what substring does? If you run just the code before the "+ RIGHT(....." section, you will return blank. That shows that your code is not working properly

Comment: Well put that in the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(AcctNumber, LEN(AcctNumber)-4) + 'XXXX' 
FROM YourTable
```

Or, if the string length is variable you'll want to avoid it erroring out on short strings:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN LEN(AcctNumber) > 4
        THEN LEFT(AcctNumber, LEN(AcctNumber)-4) + 'XXXX' 
        ELSE 'XXXX'
    END
FROM YourTable
```

Alternatively, if you're **super-sure** the account number is always 15 characters:

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(AcctNumber, 11) + 'XXXX' 
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks Russell

Answer (score 4):

You could use STUFF for this also. It was designed for this exact type of thing. I am using the excellent sample data posted by Sami. There should be no difference in performance but it is a little bit fewer keystrokes. :) The other advantage is it won't crash if the account code passed in is too short. It will just return NULL.

```
declare @MyStrings TABLE (
       STR VARCHAR(200)
    );

INSERT INTO @MyStrings VALUES
('123400012341234'),
('123400012340000004321'),
('12340102');


select stuff(STR, len(STR) - 3, 4, 'xxxx')
from @MyStrings
```

Comment: Good stuff Sean, well done.
`The other advantage is it won't crash if the account code passed in is too short. It will just return NULL`
That's how thoughtful, well written SQL queries should work IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE MyStrings (
       STR VARCHAR(200)
    );

INSERT INTO MyStrings VALUES
('123400012341234'),
('123400012340000004321'),
('12340102'),
('1');

SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(STR) >= 8 THEN SUBSTRING(STR, 1, LEN(STR)-4)+'XXXX' END AS Result
FROM MyStrings;
```

Results:

```
+-----------------------+
|        Result         |
+-----------------------+
| 12340001234XXXX       |
| 12340001234000000XXXX |
| 1234XXXX              |
| NULL                  |
+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the stuff function it's much easier:

```
 Select 
 AcctNumber=STUFF ( AcctNumber, (LEN(AcctNumber)-3), 4 , 'XXXX' )
 from Table1
```

hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

I used this query on ORACLE SQL to find the expected output;

create table acc_study(acc_no int not null);
insert into acc_study values(123400012341234);

select length(Acc_no),rpad(rpad(acc_no,11,'*'),15,'*') as output from acc_study;

output result-12340001234XXXX

Comment: This question is explicitly about Microsoft SQL Server, not Oracle, so your answer doesn’t answer the question. Be sure to pay attention to the tags when responding to a question.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    REPEAT('x', CHAR_LENGTH(account_number) - 4),
    SUBSTRING(account_number, -4)
) AS masked_account_number
FROM your_table_name;
```